# Why are bald heads so "shiny"?

Tags: human-biology, skin, hair

Why do males with baldness have  shiny skin on their head, whereas we don't experience such "shiny skin" in other parts of body without hair.

Comment: There are products to put on your head to make it more shiny.

Comment: I always thought that bald people put some clear polish on there heads

Answer (score 10):

Think of what happens when you don't wash your hair for days. It gets oily and greasy. This oil-like substance on your hair is called sebum and mainly works as a lubricant . The Sebaceous glands responsible for excreting sebum don't stop working when the hair follicles attached to them do. The result is a "shiny" head.

Comment: Actually people "shine" there heads on purpose. There are products sold for this.

Comment: Some do. Their bodies either doesn't produce enough sebum or they want a more "shiny" look. A slight shiness is natural in any bald head though.

Comment: Do bald people not wash their heads frequently?  And why is my chin not shiny if I shave regularly?

Comment: @jamesqf Well you have made an excellent point and it has really made me reopen this question. This sebum theory is good but incompletely explains the question.

Comment: I have seen many people who keep washing their head as well but still have "shiny" head. It doesn't explain it fully I am afraid.

Comment: Washing your head every single day dries it out, hence triggering the excessive production of sebum instead of hindering it.

Answer (score 0):

It’s due to fibrosis. Men with androgenic allopecia suffer from chronic inflammation of the scalp. Male pattern baldness is a poorly understood disease, but what most people don’t know is that it’s an auto immune skin condition. The hormone DHT appears to trigger a cascade of events leading to inflammation and fibrosis This results in a build up of scar tissue, I.e. fibrosis that gives a swollen and shiny look to the scalp. Scalp fibrosis results in reduced blood flow and hair follicles shrinkage and eventual death.  https://perfecthairhealth.com/the-ultimate-hair-loss-flowchart-why-we-lose-our-hair/
You may not realize it, but claims that bald men’s heads are shiny due to sweat and grease is quite insulting to people suffering from an embarassing and irritating auto immune disease. It’s just an uneducated guess in the truest sense. An attempt to explain something without having done any research into the subject. Armpits are usually sweaty and produce oils but are never shiny.

Comment: Interesting answer. Can you please add some references to it?

Comment: Welcome. Please refrain from shooting at other answers and focus on writing a good answer by providing sources to your claims.  I've toned down your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Skin produces a material called Sebum which is naturally shiny, on skin with hair much of this is absorbed by the hair. In addition the skin over the top of the head is very smooth and fairly taunt because the skin does not undergo much flexion. Smooth surfaces are shiny, skin on a bald head is often smooth and taught (which makes it smoother) which makes reflectivity more [even](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1600-0846.2011.00537.x) which makes it shinier (glossier) . Smooth taught skin and sebum oils and waxes [contribute](http://www.dl.begellhouse.com/en/references/1bb331655c289a0a,2d0ea52e222856c3,4dd661c9776712d0.html?year=2018) to being shiny, so even if say your face is not normally shiny the above combination makes the skin on the head shiny. Drying of the skin can also [contribute](https://www.osapublishing.org/boe/abstract.cfm?uri=boe-8-9-3981).

Note how people in with uncommonly smooth and hairless skin any large smooth taunt patch (like the thigh or cheek) will also often be shiny (glossy) unless they use makeup.